# Acknowledgements

Tags: contributions

I am used to working in Raiser's Edge and DonorPerfect. I am having trouble figuring out how to process acknowledgments in Civi. Is there a way to set up a series of letter templates so that I can assign a letter to each donation and process a group of donations all at once using a word format?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "process a group of donations all at once using a word format".  Do you mean that you want to export to a .doc file?  Could you also please update the question to specify the version of CiviCRM you're using?

Answer (score 2):

you have a feature to generate pdf letters. You can set up a template and generate the pdf directly.

If you need more advanced merge features and want to work from your word processor, I'd suggest you to export as a csv and do a mail merge with it.

Comment: Newer versions of CiviCRM can generate a .doc file directly from within CiviCRM, but it's not clear (to me) from the wording if that's what this person is interested in.